# A batch file which runs a command on the first query result?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a batch file that will invoke a command by a specific query.

So I have

```
aaa-test-01.txt
b-test-a-02.txt
cc-test-03.txt //newset
```

Query :

```
dir *test*.txt /o-d
```

(get all custom files , order by date desc)

And now I want to open the first result with notepad.

**Question**

How can I create a batch file so that I will be able to run it like :

```
run.bat *test*.txt
```

The batch file should have something like :

```
notepad %the file%
```

Basically, I want to open notepad with the last latest file.

Comment: @Compo why did you do `OD` instead of `O-d` ? with your example it runs on the oldest file not the newest file ......?

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you run the command in a `For /F` loop, reverse the date order so that it returns and acts on the newest first before exiting the loop, *(thus preventing the next file from being acted upon)*.

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B /A:-D /O:-D /T:C "*-test-*.txt" 2^>Nul') Do @Start "" Notepad "%%A" & Exit /B
```

The example above uses the most recently `C`reated date, as opposed to the `A`ccessed or `W`ritten *(default)*, enter `dir /?` at the [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt) to see the usage information available for the `Dir` command.

Comment: can you please elaborate on `2^>Nul` ? I know that `>` create a file

Comment: I'm redirecting any STDERR output from the `Dir`, because if there were no matching text files, the returned error message would pass to the `Do`. If you send it to the NUL device instead, nothing will pass and the loop wouldn't run a `Do` in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A variable can be set by redirecting input from a file.

=== run.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\firstfile.tmp"
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /B /A:-D /O:-D "%~1"') DO (ECHO>"%TEMPFILE%" %%~f")
SET /P "FIRSTFILE=" <"%TEMPFILE%"
notepad "%FIRSTFILE%"
IF EXIST "%TEMPFILE%" (DEL "%TEMPFILE%")
```

At the command prompt, simply run the .bat file script.

```
CALL run.bat *test*.txt
```

If you wanted to push ahead into PowerShell and have the current version 5 or higher, this could be used.

```
Get-ChildItem -File '*test*.txt' |
    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime |
    Select-Object -First 1 |
    ForEach-Object { & notepad $_.Name }
```

Comment: You do not need to type the SET command. It is already in the .bat file script. All you need to do is run `run.bat` from the command line.